# Create new Site with custom Template Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I need to create a new site with a custom template, I have saved the template via sharepoint designer, now how can i create the new site under the url: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-new-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to create a new site collection using custom template in SharePoint Online:

1. Go to SharePoint Online admin center to create.

In the site collection section, create a site collection and select “select template later” under Custom category, and continue with the new site collection creation process. Navigate the new site collection url, upload the site template to the Solution Gallery, then activate this template.

Reference: [create a new site collection in SharePoint Online admin center](http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html)

2. Using PowerShell script to create.

Reference: [create a new site collection in SharePoint Online using PowerShell script](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/create-site-collection-custom-template-using-power-shell-script-part-1/)